# Windows C Runtime library not linking like I expect?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Being a long-time POSIX/Linux/BSD C developer and now trying to do a few things with Visual C++ 2010, I'm kind of fumbling around with the tooling because it doesn't quite work the same as the GCC toolset does.  In theory, at least according to the docs, it seems very similar (and I'm sure it is), but I'm not seeing the things I'm expecting to see.

In this case, I'm trying to build a C library for later use in a .NET project, and I want to be careful to avoid runtime conflicts later on.  My thought was to build a static library, linked against a DLL version of the C runtime (msvcr100d.dll in the Debug config) so I set the `/MDd` flag.  However, when I use `dumpbin.exe` to inspect the resulting .lib output, it shows no dependents or imports.

Two questions, really:

1. Is this a bad idea in the first place?  Should I be building a DLL or linking against the static CRT instead?
2. Why doesn't `dumpbin.exe` show the dependency on the CRT when I use `/MDd`?

**Update**: [Choosing the Correct C/C++ Runtime Library](http://www.davidlenihan.com/2008/01/choosing_the_correct_cc_runtim.html) is pretty helpful and informative.  I tried the `dumpbin` incantation he suggests, and the output shows that the lib does link to `msvcrtd` as expected, but that doesn't really answer my second question above.

Comment: Wow.  I'm still google searching this issue, and this question is already #4 in searches involving "dumpbin" and "dependents".  They must crawl this site continuously.

Comment: Unless you are using C++/CLI it should feel nearly identical.  With that said...Code...Please!!  If/When you update the question to a point where I can address specific questions I will post an answer to your questions.

Comment: @Ramhound: um...code is irrelevant to this question.  This is a tooling issue.  I have specific questions already articulated.  If you can't address them, it's not because I haven't explained the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is not a final EXE or DLL there is no import section.  Instead, there are linker directives that say how this lib would like to be linked.

```
dumpbin /directives thoraway.lib

Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


  Dump of file throwaway.lib

  File Type: LIBRARY

  Linker Directives
  -----------------
  /FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1600"
  /FAILIFMISMATCH:"_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2"
  /DEFAULTLIB:"msvcprtd"
  /DEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRTD"
  /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES"
  /EDITANDCONTINUE

 Summary

     CFC .debug$S
      4C .debug$T
      A2 .drectve
       B .rdata
       4 .rtc$IMZ
       4 .rtc$TMZ
      49 .text
```